# query takes a long time 'selecting' nothing

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a query that I ran in thrift that takes a very long time. I run it on a single partition of a table which has 500k rows.

the query looks like this:

```
select col0 from <table> where partition=<partition> and <col1>=<val>
```

I made it so `col1 != val`, so the query returns 0 rows.

This query takes about a 30 seconds (a minute if I use `select *`).

When I run the exact same query but with `select count(col0)` it takes 2 seconds.

**What could cause queries to take a long time with `select col` but not with `select count(col)`?**

Here's the queries explained

```
explain select col0 from table where `partition` = partition and col=val;
```

> *Project [col0#607]
>   +- *Filter (isnotnull(col1#607) && (col1#607 = aaaa))
>      +- *FileScan parquet 
> table[col1#607,partition#611]
>      Batched: true,
>      Format: Parquet,
>      Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[...,
>      PartitionCount: 23,
>      PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(partition#611),
>      (cast(partition#611 as int) = partition_name)],
>      PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(col1),
>      EqualTo(col1,aaaa)],
>      ReadSchema: struct

```
explain select count(col0) from table where `partition` = partition and col=val;
```

> *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[count(col0#625)])
>   +- Exchange SinglePartition
>      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(col0#625)])
>         +- *Project [col0#625]
>            +- *Filter (isnotnull(col1#625) && (col1#625 = aaaa))
>               +- *FileScan parquet 
> table[col1#625,partition#629]
>               Batched: true,
>               Format: Parquet,
>               Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[...,
>               PartitionCount: 23,
>               PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(partition#629),
>               (cast(partition#629 as int) = partition_name)],
>               PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(col1),
>               EqualTo(col1,aaaa)],
>               ReadSchema: struct

As far as I can tell, the process is exactly the same, only the `count` query has more steps. So how come it's 15x faster?

**Edit**:

I found this interesting nugget in the logs:

*with count*:

> 18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8092, ip-123456, executor 36, partition 0, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8093, ip-123456, executor 35, partition 1, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8094, ip-123456, executor 36, partition 2, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8095, ip-123456, executor 35, partition 3, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8096, ip-123456, executor 36, partition 4, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8097, ip-123456, executor 35, partition 5, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8098, ip-123456, executor 36, partition 6, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8099, ip-123456, executor 35, partition 7, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8100, ip-123456, executor 36, partition 8, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:42:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 2509.0 (TID 8101, ip-123456, executor 35, partition 9, RACK_LOCAL, 5521 bytes)

- without: *

> 18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO TaskSetManager: **Starting task 0.0** in stage 2512.0 (TID 8136, ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 37, partition 1, RACK_LOCAL, 5532 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2352_piece0 in memory on ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal:40489 (size: 12.6 KB, free: 11.6 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2512.0 (TID 8136) in 667 ms on ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 37) (1/1) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 2512.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2512 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) finished in 0.668 s 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2293 finished: getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220, took 0.671740 s 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2294 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) with 1 output partitions 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2513 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 2513 (MapPartitionsRDD[312] at run at AccessController.java:0), which has no missing parents 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2353 stored as values in memory (estimated size 66.6 KB, free 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2353_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 12.6 KB, free 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2353_piece0 in memory on 10.117.48.68:41493 (size: 12.6 KB, free: 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2353 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1047 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 2513 (MapPartitionsRDD[312] at run at AccessController.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions  
> Vector(2))
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 2513.0 with 1 tasks 
>   18/06/28 11:45:32 INFO TaskSetManager: **Starting task 0.0** in stage 2513.0 (TID 8137, ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 37, partition 2, RACK_LOCAL, 5532 bytes) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2353_piece0 in memory on ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal:40489 (size: 12.6 KB, free: 11.6 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2513.0 (TID 8137) in 5238 ms on ip-10-117-49-97.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 37) (1/1) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 2513.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2513 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) finished in 5.238 s 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2294 finished: getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220, took 5.242084 s 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2295 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) with 1 output partitions 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2514 (getNextRowSet at OperationManager.java:220) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 2514 (MapPartitionsRDD[312] at run at AccessController.java:0), which has no missing parents 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2354 stored as values in memory (estimated size 66.6 KB, free 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2354_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 12.6 KB, free 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2354_piece0 in memory on 10.117.48.68:41493 (size: 12.6 KB, free: 12.1 GB) 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2354 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1047 
>   18/06/28 11:45:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 2514 (MapPartitionsRDD[312] at run at AccessController.java:0) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(3))

(i.e. it repeats this block, looks like it runs tasks sequentially ant not in parallel like in the count case)

I also tried doing "order by" and it actually made the query run 2x **faster**

---

Running the same query on the same data using spark instead of thrift was much faster.

I run thrift on aws emr-5.11.1

Hive 2.3.2

Spark 2.2.1

thrift 0.11.0

Comment: Thrift does not run queries. It is a RPC protocol used by Facebook, also used by Hive _(developed @Facebook)_ for its Metastore API and for its JDBC wire protocol. Hive runs queries.

Comment: Spark also uses Thrift for its JDBC wire protocol (and uses the same JDBC driver). Same for Impala.

Comment: Hive is a **batch** query engine. It has to spawn a YARN job, allocate containers, start the Mapper and Reducer phases (with lots of I/O in between), wait for job completion. Spark is also a batch query engine but it pre-allocates containers (or even does not use containers) and runs its query in-memory. All that is common knowledge for anyone even remotely interested in Data Processing and Big Data.

Comment: For faster Hive execution: install TEZ batch framework and use instead of MapReduce => queries will run 2-6x faster. Or install LLAP service (developed by HortonWorks, may not be available in EMR) with its persistent containers and memory cache grid, and it may blow out Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had this flag

```
spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true
```

in thriftserver. It collects the output from every worker sequentially which is what creates this massive overhead. Removing the flag fixed the issue. I guess it's optimized to not do is sequentially when doing "count", as it will necessarily not have a lot of data.